# Rename style name in Word via Applescript

Tags: ms-word, applescript, word-style

I wanna change the style name from "bib" to "bibliography" via Applescript. My script runs no error but style name not been changed. Anyone can help this?

Here is my script to rename style name:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word" to activate
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    if exists (Word style "bib" of active document) then
        set filename to full name of active document
        organizer rename source filename name "bib" new name "bibliography" organizer object type organizer object styles
    end if
end tell
```

However, delete style "bib" works via this script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word" to activate
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    if exists (Word style "bib" of active document) then
        set filename to full name of active document
        organizer delete source filename name "bib" organizer object type organizer object styles
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Two things: `set filename to name…`. `Full name` is the path whereas the command requires exclusively the ending part, e.g. `file.docx`. Also, your first script (rename) worked for me when using `document 1` rather than `active document`, so `set filename to name of document 1`.

Comment: 1. I got it. 2.`set filename to name of document 1` still not works for me.

Comment: That's strange. I used it to go back and forth between the two names multiple times. Sorry it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    if exists (Word style "bib" of active document) then
        set name local of Word style "bib" of active document to "bibliography"
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: You don't need two 'tell word' commands. Line 1: `tell application "Microsoft Word"`; 2: `activate`; 3: `if exists….`